# Combine two greps into a single command

Tags: sed, awk, grep, regular-expression, xml

I have some XML that looks something like this:

```
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I want to extract the version, i.e. `1.14.0-SNAPSHOT`. I know how to do it using two greps and a pipe:

```
$ grep -A1 "<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>" pom.xml | grep -Eo "\d+.\d+.\d+-SNAPSHOT"
```

How can I combine the two into one? Would I be better off using awk or sed for this task?

Comment: Why don't you use a tool designed to parse/process `xml` ?

Comment: @don_crissti fair question, but I want to be able to share this script with the rest of my team without asking them to install any special packages.

Answer (score 2):

If you sure for `<version>` on next line after `myproject`

```
sed -n '
    \|<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>|{
        n                                           #get next line
        s|[[:blank:]]*</\?version>[[:blank:]]*||gp  #remove tags and print
    }
' pom.xml
```

Or if you have **pgrep**

```
grep -zoP '<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>\s*\n\s*<version>\K[^<]+' pom.xml
```

Comment: That sed command throws an error: `sed: 3: "
    \|<artifactId>mypr ...": extra characters at the end of n command`

Answer (score 2):

You've mentioned in comments that you want something portable. That's admirable, but I'd really urge you to not do that anyway. `XML` is a contextual language, and regex isn't. There's simply no way a regular expression can parse XML correctly as a result.

At best - you get a hack, that's only valid provided the XML stays in the same format. But as the XML spec says that format can chance and retain the same semantics, that's a dangerous assumption and creates brittle code.

I know you have reasons to want to do this - you already have an answer that gives you a way to. I would suggest that a parser is still the *right* answer.

But with XML parsers, you get `xpath` - which is a lot like regular expressions,  but is applicable to hierarchical information.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA );

my $version = $twig -> get_xpath('//item/artifactId[string()="myproject"]/../version',0)->text;
print $version;

__DATA__
<xml>
  <item>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </item>
</xml>
```

Hopefully you can see how that `xpath` is working? `//item` finds an item anywhere within the structure. `[string()=` queries the text content. You could instead do something like `[@someAtt="fish"]` to check an attribute.

Then we `..` up (to `item`) and get the `version` element. 
Then get the `text` value.

As a oneliner:

```
perl -MXML::Twig -0777 -e 'print XML::Twig -> parse ( <> ) -> get_xpath('/item/artifactId[string()="myproject"]/../version',0)->text,"\n"    yourxmlfile.xml
```

Now, I'm suggesting `XML::Twig` because I think it's easier to learn. `XML::LibXML` is also quite good.

But it's distributed with strawberry perl on Windows, and is readily available in a lot of package managers - or from `CPAN`.

Alternatively - `xmlstarlet` should allow you to do much the same thing.